# PHP SQL SERVER Login credentials script

Tags: php, pdo, sqlsrv

Having trouble find a PHP script to helps users to get authenticated into a form using already existing credentials database, tried several scripts but everyone of them seems to get stuck on the same code `$sth->execute(array("uname" => $_POST["username"], "upass" => $encryptedpassword));`. For the record, we already have an existing credentials database used to for another web application, for testing purpose I've created a dummy database with plain text users' credentials, see next.

```
<?php  
$encryptedpassword = md5($_POST['password']);

$db_myHost = "SERVERNAME";
$db_myUser= "sa";
$db_myPassword = "PASWORD";
$db_myDatabase = "DATABASE"

$dbconn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$db_myHost;Database=$db_myDatabase",$db_myUser,$db_myPassword);

try
  {
  $dbPDO = new PDO('sqlsrv:server='.$db_myHost.';Database='.$db_myDatabase, $db_myUser, $db_myPassword);

  $dbPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  }
catch  (PDOException $e)
  {
    echo "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "
";
    die();
  }

//Check user credentials
$sth = $dbconn->prepare("SELECT * FROM wblgntst WHERE uname = :username AND upass = :password");

//CODE CAUSING ISSUE
$sth->execute(array("uname" => $_POST["username"], "upass" => $encryptedpassword));

    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      session_start();
    $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['uname'];
    header("Location: list.php");
    }

?>
```

ERROR

> PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid
>   parameter number: parameter was not defined in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\salesportal\php\login.php on line 28

Comment: Your placeholders are `:username` and `:password`

Comment: You shouldnt use MD5 hashing anymore. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php

Comment: @u_mulder what do you mean with my placeholders are `:username` and `:password`?

Comment: @u_mulder OK, I got it, the line should be like next `$sth->execute(array(:username => $_POST["username"], :password => $encryptedpassword));` I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

Stopped looking for some scripts, found the real solution: [Zubrag.com](http://www.zubrag.com/)